# Indesign Expandable Textbox

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I know there is a way to create an expandable / collapsible text box in Indesign. Been on W3 Schools, Youtube, and Lynda.

Anybody out there done this before?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on you InDesign version. From CS6 and upwards, See text frame options > auto-size